# WPF listboxitem PreviewKeyDown

Tags: wpf, listbox, prism-4

I have a listbox that is bound to a list of custom objects. I can get the listbox items to display correctly using the ListBox.ItemTemplate in xaml. The custom objects for the listbox are all of the same base class outlined below.

```
public class HomeViewMenuItem : UIElement
{
    private Uri _uri;
    private IRegionManager _manager;

    public HomeViewMenuItem(string text, Uri uri, IRegionManager manager)
    {
        this.PreviewMouseDown += HomeViewMenuItem_PreviewMouseDown;
        this.PreviewKeyDown += HomeViewMenuItem_PreviewKeyDown;
        _manager = manager;
        Text = text;
        _uri = uri;
        ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.Click, this.CanClick);
    }

    void HomeViewMenuItem_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            this.ClickCommand.Execute();
        }
    }

    void HomeViewMenuItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        this.ClickCommand.Execute();
    }

    private void Click()
    {
        _manager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].RequestNavigate(_uri);
    }

    private bool CanClick()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public DelegateCommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I am having is the HomeViewMenuItem_PreviewKeyDown method is not getting called. I believe this is because the method is getting called on the ListBoxItem itself first and getting handled there. I was able to verify this by obtaining a reference to the ListBoxItem object through listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) after the ItemContainerGenerator status changes to ContainersGenerated and adding an event handler there. This event handler correctly fired. Normally this would be an ok solution on a small project but I plan on having more listboxes with the same sort of functionality and would like to have a simpler/better solution. Is there a way that I can get my base class previewkeydown method to work?

The only solution I could think of is to have the base class inherit from ListBoxItem instead of UIElement then get the ListBox to create my items instead of ListBoxItems. But I dont think that is really possible without creating my own ListBox implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be somewhat confused. In WPF, we create *data items* and declare `DataTemplate`s to define what those items should look like in the UI. Our data items do *not* extend UI classes. If you *have* to handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event, then attach a handler to the *UI element* in the `DataTemplate` instead:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid PreviewKeyDown="HomeViewMenuItem_PreviewKeyDown">
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: No confusion, what you suggest is what I already had when I started. I want a more reusable solution as I need the keydown functionality elsewhere. Ill mark your answer as correct as it answers the question I asked, although I ended up creating a custom implementation of listbox and listboxitem so that I can reuse it elsewhere.